# How to programmatically check installed other application has grant the draw over apps permission?

Tags: java, android, system

How can I programmatically check the permission in Settings -> Apps -> Draw over other apps is granted for other installed apps?
I used the below function to check the Draw over other apps permission for the app.

`Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)`

This will check the application itself permission is granted or not but I want to check for the other app.
Thanks